# Writing to SQL yields different results with shell / django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a simple model:

```
class myJSONField(models.JSONField):
    def get_prep_value(self, v):
        if v is None:
            return value
        return json.dumps(v, ensure_ascii = False)

class Product(models.Model):
    data                = myJSONField()
    number              = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

`Product.create(number = 1, data = {"direction": "süd"})` yields:

```
"{\"direction\": \"s\u00fcd\"}"
```

Testing with sqlite3:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
c = conn.cursor()
test = json.dumps({"direction": "Süd"}, ensure_ascii = False)
sql = ("""UPDATE test_product SET data = ? WHERE id=1""")
c.execute(sql, [test])
conn.commit()
```

yields:

```
{"direction": "süd"}
```

I am using the same `db.sqlite3` file for both tests.

1. I do not understand why the `ensure_ascii = False` flag is ignored by the django logic.
2. How can I obtain a correct JSON in my JSONField (without the escaped `"`)?

Edit: I can see the result in my django admin and I also tested omitting the `ensure_ascii = False` setting in SQLite:

```
a = {"direction": "Süd", }
b = json.dumps(a)#, ensure_ascii = False)
sql = ("""UPDATE test_product SET data = ? WHERE id=1""")
c.execute(sql, [b])
conn.commit()
```

which leads to:

```
{"direction": "S\u00fcd"}
```

(remark: no `"` around that one!)

When **writing to the database with Django** and **reading** via `python manage.py shell` and **`sqlite3`** directly:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT * FROM virtualShelf_product WHERE id=1')
res = c.fetchall()


[(1, 1, '"{\\"direction\\": \\"s\\u00fcd\\"}"')]
```

when **reading** the same product via **Django ORM**:

```
p = Product.objects.get(id=1)
p.data
'{"direction": "süd"}'
```

Comment: Is this maybe using the dictionary's repr() when converting the value from database form back to a Python object? When you see `"{\"direction\": \"s\u00fcd\"}"`, is that from viewing the database, from Python, or something else?

Comment: This is how it is in the SQLite viewer and also the django admin shows it that way.

Comment: @xtlc: but how do you show these, do you use the same method for both to *inspect* the value in the database? Not to insert it, but to see the value in the database?

Comment: Beware that `get_prep_value` is post-processed with `get_db_prep_value`.

Comment: this is a bit tricky, because in the shell python automatically does read `\u00fcd` -> `ü` when reading via the ORM with `Product.objects.get(...)`. But I tried to make it visible in my original post. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @xtlc: well it appears you encoded the JSON twice, once through `get_prep_value`, and second time to `get_db_prep_value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By overriding `get_prep_value`, you are serializing twice. Indeed, once in your `myJSONField`, and a second time by the `get_db_prep_value` function which uses `get_prep_value` as a helper function.

Indeed, if we inspect the [source code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/07b7a3ab7573a0685975602c437ce4795a8885e7/django/db/models/fields/json.py#L101-L131), we see:

> ```
> def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
>     if not prepared:
>         value = self.get_prep_value(value)
>     # …
>     return connection.ops.adapt_json_value(value, self.encoder)
> ```

depending on the connection itself, Django can then send for example a BSON blob, or a JSON. Except for PostgreSQL, it [encodes the data with <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/07b7a3ab7573a0685975602c437ce4795a8885e7/django/db/backends/base/operations.py#L584):

```
def adapt_json_value(self, value, encoder):
    return json.dumps(value, cls=encoder)
```

if you override `get_prep_value`, it converts it to a string, and then you JSON serialize it a second time.

One can implement a custom backend that would pass `ensure_ascii=False`, a poor man's solution would be to just inject this through *monkey* patching. For example in the `AppConfig`:

```
# app_name/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig


class AppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "app_name"

    def ready(self):
        def adapt_json_value(self, value, encoder):
            return json.dumps(value, ensure_ascii=False, cls=encoder)

        from django.db.backends.base.operations import BaseDatabaseOperations

        BaseDatabaseOperations.adapt_json_value = adapt_json_value
```

of course we then omit the `get_prep_value` in the `myJSONField`, which also basically nullifies `myJSONField` over `JSONField`.

Comment: this seems to work with SQLite and PostgreSQL - your choice of words makes me wonder, what would be a "robust" solution to tackle this? Where would I start?

Comment: @xtlc: make a custom backend, like `django.db.backends.sqlite3json` that subclasses `sqlite3` for example with an override.