# implementing custom backend is not recognized by django

Tags: django, django-models

Following the usually smart [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76748740/4225972) from one of djangos experts I want to implement my own backend, overwriting SQLite3 and Postgres JSON handling method.

What I did:

1. created a `backends` folder in my app directory:
   [image: dir structure]
2. put base.py in there

   ```
   from django.db.backends.base.operations import BaseDatabaseOperations
   from django.db.backends.sqlite3.base import DatabaseWrapper as DBW
   import json

   class BaseDatabaseOperationsJSON(BaseDatabaseOperations):
       def adapt_json_value(self, value, encoder):
           print("should be called")
           return json.dumps(value, ensure_ascii = False, cls = encoder)


   class DatabaseWrapper(DBW):
       ops_class = BaseDatabaseOperationsJSON
   ```
3. changed `settings.py` accordingly (so I thought):

   ```
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': "Shelf.backends.sqlite3json",
           'NAME': BASE_DIR.joinpath("db.sqlite3"),
       }
   }
   ```

This throws the error:

```
NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseDatabaseOperations may require a quote_name() method
```

Comment: the error says `django.db.backends.sqlite3json`?

Comment: that's right, I just copied & pasted the error. Why are you asking specifically for this?

Comment: because the engine is `Shelf.backends`, not `django.db.backends`?

Comment: one step further: after deactivating and activating the virtual environment, I now get no error message, but also no effect - so I guess your thought was correct, that was probably some in between coding error I copied. But unfortunately I now get no error or whatsoever.

Comment: are you sure it constructs an object, what if you override the `__init__` to print something?

Comment: added `print("test")` in the `__init__.py` on the level of the `base.py`. This results in: `Shelf\backends\sqlite3json\__init__.py changed, reloading.` console: `test`.

Comment: does it call the `adapt_json_value` method? We can check that through printing as well.

Comment: I added a `print("test")` to `venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\operations.py`'s `adapt_json_value` and it get's printed every time I write something to the db - so the overwrite is not in place?

Comment: Ah ok, your suggestion is basically what I tried too, just wrapped up from the other end. No it does not print anything if I add a `print` statement there.

Comment: Hold on: the method is defined on the `Operations`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/95e4d6b81312fdd9f8ebf3385be1c1331168b5cf/django/db/backends/base/operations.py#L16 so you should override the `operations` and plug the new class into the backend.

Comment: I also tried to deliberately put a wrong string into `Engine` in `settings.py` under `DATABASES` which leads to the same error as I posted in my original post - so something IS being checked at least.

Comment: I edited the original post to reflect my changes after your last comment. I see changes in the error now.

Comment: you probably should subclass `from django.db.backends.sqlite3.operations import DatabaseOperations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were quite close, you should only subclass the operations class of `sqlite3` since it contains already logic how to quote names, etc:

```
import json

from django.db.backends.sqlite3.base import DatabaseWrapper as DBW
from django.db.backends.sqlite3.operations import DatabaseOperations


class BaseDatabaseOperationsJSON(DatabaseOperations):
    def adapt_json_value(self, value, encoder):
        return json.dumps(value, ensure_ascii=False, cls=encoder)


class DatabaseWrapper(DBW):
    ops_class = BaseDatabaseOperationsJSON
```